# ASP.NET MVC3 Cache object

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, caching

I have an Util class that goes through multiple xml files. Since there may be many of them I want to cache their data. So, how (and is it even possible) can I get to the application's Cache object? I know I can use it in my controllers through HttpContext.Cache, but in other classes?

Ah, when I try to construct Cache object in my Util class I get NullReferenceException...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try 
using System.Web;

and then use HttpContext.Current.Cache

in your Util class.  That's what I see working.